# DAX Userelationship function

Tags: powerbi, relationship, dax, powerpivot

I have this issue with Userelationship function in DAX. 
I have two Tables **SalesFact** and **DimPromoSkus** like this:

Diagram View.

[image: Diagram View]

The 2 tables in Data View are like this:

Data View

[image: Data View]

The 2 tables are linked from **SkuCampaign1**, **SkuCampaign2**, **SkuCampaign3** in the **SalesFact** to the **SkuCampaign** from the DimPromoSkus.

So basically the goal of DimPromoSkus table is to indicate if the product was in campaign C1, C2 or C3. 
For example the campaign C1 happened between days 1/1/2019 to 4/1/2019 but only SKUS A1 and A2 were selled on Promotion. A2 and A3 were off promo but sold during campaign C1 period.

My goal is to calculate Promoted Sales on each Campaign C1,C2 and C3. Of course this could be done with a lookupcolumn and then calculate the Sales where that key was found BUT I would like to use **USERELATIONSHIP** function.

So, to calculate PromoSales for campaign C1 my measure in Theory should be:

```
PromoSalesC1:=CALCULATE(SUM(SalesFact[Sales]);USERELATIONSHIP(SalesFact[SkuCampaign1];DimPromoSkus[SkuCampaign]))
```

The result obtained should be 25 but is returning me 155 which is the total sum of the rows so is not doing really nothing
The result keeps giving 155 if I use SkuCampaign2 or SkuCampaign3 which are inactive relations but **USERELATIONSHIP** should activate this..

Any idea of what is going on or am I missing something? :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StelioK is correct that you need a way for the measure to apply a filter context to the sum. You don't need to explicitly supply a value though. You can simply pass in the `DimPromoSkus` table as the filter context.

```
PromoSalesC1 =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(SalesFact[Sales]),
        DimPromoSkus,
        USERELATIONSHIP(SalesFact[SkuCampaign1], DimPromoSkus[SkuCampaign])
    )
```

Remember that the `CALCULATE` function can take tables as filter arguments. Here, we provide `DimPromoSkus` as the filter so that we don't sum any values that don't flow through the specified relationship. So, for example, since `A3 C1` isn't in `DimPromoSkus`, the corresponding row in `SalesFact` doesn't get included in the sum.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks Alexis! Would these produce the same results?

Comment: In this case, I think so, but for more general scenarios where you had, for example, multiple codes associated with `Campaign1` (e.g. `C10`, `C11`, `C12`) you wouldn't just be able to specify one and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The DAX is doing exactly what it is intended to do. By calling the USERELATIONSHIP function you are 'activating' the relationship but you still need to provide a filter context either through a slicer or in the DAX itself.

Use the code below and see if it helps

```
PromoSalesC1 :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( SalesFact[Sales] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( SalesFact[SkuCampaign1], DimPromoSkus[SkuCampaign] ),
    DimPromoSkus[Campaign] = 'C1'
)
```